# uitableview inside uiscrollview storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I have a `UIScrollView` in storyboard and a `UITableView` in storyboard as well. The point is that I want to put inside the scrollview several instances of that `UITableView`. But I get an error

`unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`

So how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Ok! Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DayCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configerCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

And I gave a cell an identifier in storyboard...

That's how I add UITableView to UIScrollView:

```
UITableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.mainScroll addSubview:tableView.view];
```

Comment: You must replace "Cell" in your -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to name that you gave your UITableViewCell prototype on storyboard.

Comment: Please post the relevant code - probably your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your tableview cell needs an identifier. Try'n click on the table view cell and under the attributes inspector there is a field named `Identifier`. Check That!